# zebra printer suddenly prints labels with an offset

Tags: zebra-printers

we have an 420t zebra printer, which suddenly started printing labels in a wrong way. Say one wanted to print a first name and a last-name on it, now it prints part only of the last name. The code that i send to the printer has not changed at all. When i try to reinstall the printer, i get a certificate error on windows 10, i have calibrated many times the printer, but other than that, i have no idea what else i should do...

i have also tried my code here, it prints correctly, so i guess it is an issue with my zebra printer setup:

http://labelary.com/viewer.html

Comment: Have you checked the printer's configuration?  Zebra printers allow manually adjusting offset using the control panel.  This offset is in addition to any offset defined by each label format.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how i could do this? "Zebra printers allow manually adjusting offset using the control panel" We use the gc420t printer @MarkWarren

Comment: Ok, that makes it harder, as those printers don't have a control panel... Can you modify the ZPL?  If so, experiment with the `^LS` (left shift) command.